# Some words/phrases from the world of software development

Tags: traduction, anglais, informatique, terminologie, professions

I'm preparing a technical document *in French* for the software development company I work for. What I would like is to know if the following terms I'm using are correct:

- *Team Lead*: **Leader d'équipe/Chef d'équipe**
- *Technical Lead*: **Responsable technique**
- *Pilot project*: **Projet pilot**
- *Release Notes*: **Notes de publication/Notes de miss-à-jour**

Can anyone confirm those translations are correct? Do you know/recommend any other terms or phrases I could use instead of those?

Comment: See also [Existe-t-il un dictionnaire anglais-français de termes techniques?](http://french.stackexchange.com/q/5818/82)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's mainly correct.

I'd suggest this, though :

- *Team Lead*: **Chef d'équipe** (your other variant might be sort of mocked for its too heavy and almost memetic business-talk feel, and pointed bad by anglicism-angry people...)
- *Technical Lead*: Responsable technique
- *Pilot project*: Projet **pilote** *(the final 'e' was lacking)*
- *Release Notes*: Notes **de version** (some variants may fit but I encounter mainly this one in professional context)

Comment: Why did you choose "**Chef d'équipe**" and not "**Chef de projet**" for *Team Lead* ? The team leader often gets some business related task just like project management.

Comment: @air-dex There're not the same. Depending on the context, these two different roles sure **can** be played by the same person, but not necessarily at all ! I think we don't have enough context to decide that, so I stayed close to the submitter's word.

Comment: @RomainVALERI In our case, the _Team Lead_ has some level of involvement with _Project Management_, like participating in the Release Plan and has direct contact with clients, but the role is more of somebody who coordinates the work of the team internally and externally. This persone is sometimes the Technical Lead, sometime not. Anyhow, I think "**Chef d'équipe**" suits our needs. You got me with that 'e', thank you!

Comment: @GabeThorns So in your case "**Chef de projet**" is (much) more convenient.

Comment: The difference between *chef d'équipe* and *chef de projet* isn't technical in itself. The former role implies how someone fits into an organization, where the latter has sense only inside a project's scope. Saying someone is *chef de projet* without naming said project is calling for the next question.... « for *which* project ? »

Comment: @air-dex In our case, the "**Chef d'équipe**"  is a persone who leads a team that can be involved in many projects inside the company (Documentation for instance, is a single team that works on several projects, and this is of course particular to the company I work for). Thus, as Romain pointed out, the scope for "**Chef d'équipe**" and "_Chef de projet_" are different in our particular case. Thanks for your observation anyway!