# Existe-t-il un dictionnaire anglais-français de termes techniques?

Tags: traduction, ressources, informatique, terminologie, dictionnaires

Je dois parfois traduire de l'anglais au français des offres d'emplois qui sont techniques (dans le domaine logiciel), et j'aimerais pouvoir utiliser un ouvrage de référence pour confirmer certains termes. Est-ce qu'il existe un dictionnaire en ligne de termes plus techniques?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Le [Grand dictionnaire terminologique](http://gdt.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/) de l'[Office québécois de la langue française](http://www.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/) est une bonne référence pour les termes techniques de tous les domaines, mais pas toujours aussi complets que des dictionnaires spécialisés dans un domaine particulier.

Pour le cas particulier de l'informatique, le [glossaire](http://glossaire.traduc.org/index.php) de [traduc.org](http://traduc.org/) est très complet.

Sinon, j'ai trouvé sur [Amazon.fr](http://www.amazon.fr/dp/2904105190) un dictionnaire papier de termes techniques, reste à voir ce qu'il vaut.

Comment: J'ai ajouté tes deux ressources à http://french.stackexchange.com/a/405/176.

Answer (score 4):

Linguee inclut des traductions de l'UE. Beaucoup de contexte. Je l'utilise beaucoup:

- http://www.linguee.com/french-english

Answer (score 2):

Si vous recherchez la traduction de termes techniques, je publie un lexique de termes techniques Anglais/Français qui sera enrichi petit à petit. Plusieurs domaines sont abordés: Mathématiques, mécanique, ingénierie, ... et l'informatique. Il existe plusieurs versions dont une avec un tri alphabétique des termes et l'autre avec un tri par domaines.

Si cela vous intéresse, vous pouvez le télécharger librement sur mon site:
http://www.jeanjoux.fr/

En espérant que cela vous sera utile.